# Different social meta previews for different subdomains

Tags: html, meta-tags, netlify

So I'm using Netlify and I have a site that’s connected to git and for simplicity there are two branches. One is the master branch and the other a developer branch.

I have separate social meta tags for the master and developer branches since the master lives on the primary domain and the developer branch lives on a subdomain.

The issue is that the preview on social media platforms shows the subdomain preview when the primary link is mentioned in a post. However the subdomain preview shows up when the subdomain is mentioned in a post.

How can I get the previews to show correctly? Here’s the [main site](https://coronavirustt.info/) and here’s the [developer site](https://developer.coronavirustt.info/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So this wasn't really a problem a `git merge` had overwritten the social meta tags on the master branch.

It all works fine now.